# How to read user's certificate in java

Tags: javascript, java, linux, x509certificate, websphere-portal

Is there a way to read the trusted certificates installed with in a client browser? I want to read information such as issued to and issued by. I'm using Java to run web-sphere portal using web-sphere to run the application.

I have written the below code for reading certificates. When the code executes I get null values.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

String cyphersuite = (String) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite");        
        if (cyphersuite != null) {
            X509Certificate[] x509=(X509Certificate[])req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
            System.out.println("x509   "+x509);         
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a list of certificates the user has installed as trusted? Can you elaborate on your use case for wanting to do that?

Comment: @Stewart Thanks for quick reply ...Through our portal application we are giving one certificate to end user. 1) user needs to install certificate on their local machine. 2) how to read user's installed certificate through httpservletrequest on server side or java code level for checking whether he/she installed certificate on their machine or not? –

Comment: How would the browser connect to your sever if the certificate is not installed?

Comment: UseCase: Assume two users are on same machine.
1)Application will give certificate for user1.
2)user1 install the certificate on his/her machine.
3)Application will give another certificate for user2,but he/she did not install certificate on same machine
4)user1 able to access the server because he/she installed the certificate on same machine
5)user2 also accessing the server with user1 certificate,because  browser has user1 certificate.
6)we are validating certificate on apache level with {SSL:SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}, but we are not validating user specific certificate

Comment: Is your server using a self signed certificate?

Comment: yes.self signed certificate

Comment: @Reddy Sura I don't see the point in your user1/user2 example. An installed certificate is like a saved password. If there are two users they should use two user profiles on the computer or at least two browser-profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. When writing server code and inspecting the request object your reading information that the client chooses to send. Browsers won't ever send arbitrary certificate information back to servers they are connecting to. If a browser was to send this kind of information servers could do things like identify other sites that the user has visited. This would be a breach of privacy.

Furthermore if the client is attempting to connect to your server and can't verify the certificate it will never create a connection to your app. The only way that your code above will execute is if the user has already trusted the certificate. At that point there is no reason to do any kind of check.